# How do I determine my flat-footed and touch AC?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

How do I figure out what my flat-footed and touch AC should be? I looked in the index, but it just takes me to a page that has a description. I looked in the glossary, and that just gives a description as well.

Comment: Silver, are there other players you are going to be playing with? Certainly your Dungeon Master can give you more in-depth and personable advice.

Comment: Dont have one yet...My mom offered, but my books are at my dads... She doesnt remember much cause the last time she played was about fifteen yrs ago

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you are [flat-footed](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#flatFooted), you lose your dexterity bonus to armor class as well as any Dodge bonus. So use the same calculation you would use for your normal armor class but don't include any bonuses from dexterity or dodge.

Against [touch attacks](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatStatistics.htm#touchAttacks), you lose any bonuses from armor, shield, and natural armor, but retain bonuses from dexterity, deflection, dodge, etc.

Comment: ty so much!!!!!